# Why does this add spaces? echo "x ax" | sed 's/x\s*/x /'

Tags: sed, regular-expression, replace

I want to find a `x`, and replace the 0 or more following spaces (`\s*`) with just a single space.

```
echo "x ax" | sed 's/x\s*/x /'
```

For some reason, instead of replacing the spaces with the single space, it just appends one space to however many existed there before:

```
x  ax
```

The use of `+` instead of `*` appears to absolutely nothing, regardless of my use of the `-E` flag.

It appears that `sed` doesn't do non-greedy expressions, so why doesn't this `*` consume all of the spaces when matching?

I'm a regex ninja in non-bash settings, but bash and its tools eat me alive.  I've got no idea how to concisely phrase this for a successful search engine query.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`sed` expects a [basic regular expression](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03) (BRE). `\s` is not a standard special construct in a BRE (nor in an [ERE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_04), for that matter), this is an extension of some languages, in particular Perl (which many others imitate). In sed, depending on the implementation, `\s` either stands for the literal string `\s` or for the literal character `s`.

In your implementation, it appears that `\s` matches `s`, so `\s*` matches 0 or more `s`, and `x\s*` matches `x` in your sample input, hence `x ax` is transformed to `x  ax` (and `xy` would be transformed to `x y` and so on). In other implementations (e.g. with GNU sed), `\s` matches `\s`, so `\s*` matches a backslash followed by 0 or more `s`, which doesn't occur in your input so the line is unchanged.

This has absolutely nothing to do with greediness. Greediness doesn't influence whether a string matches a regex, only what portion of the string is captured by a match.

Comment: I believe you are the most correct.  I tried apparently every combination of character class that I could think of, but using a literal space makes this regex work with the version of `sed` I'm using.  What boggles my mind, however, is the use of the valid flag `-E` on this system to enable ERE, I also cannot successfully use `[:space:]`, which my `man re_format` says is acceptable.  Nothing but a literal ` ` works here.

Comment: @Tim What sed implementation are you using? Did you write `x[[:space:]]` and not `x[:space:]`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting your sed and grep flags mixed up.  -E is the grep flag for extended regular expressions.  -r is the sed flag for extended regular expressions.   The following works for me:

```
echo "x     ax" | sed -r 's/x\s*/x /'
```

It produces

```
x ax
```

Comment: Hum.  I'm realizing belatedly that BSD `sed` manpages are looking pretty different right about now.  `-r` isn't a valid flag on this system.  I need to regroup and figure out what's up.

Comment: @Tim Stephen is refering to the flags of GNU grep.